# How do you implement Size-Class-Specific Layout without storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, autolayout

I need to create a bit different versions of layout for different size classes, and I need to do that without storyboard.

I wonder what is the best way to do that? So far, I have two options:

1) Just remove all old constraints in `traitCollectionDidChange()` and set up new set of constraints.

2) Store all constraints in my ViewController and modify them in `traitCollectionDidChange()`.

Second option seems to me to be better but I still have doubt :)

Comment: Well both of them are same if you look at it. Modify existing ones or to remove old ones and create new ones, which modification would do otherwise. I would like to see some other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your constraints in your view controller - preferably in arrays if possible. Then, use **viewWillTransition(to:size:)** to activate/deactivate.

```
var wC = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var wR = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var hC = [NSLayoutConstraint]()
var hR = [NSLayoutConstraint]()

override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    // use following two lines if width changes from compact to regular
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(wC)
    NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(wR)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your tip ;) To hold two separate sets of constraints seems to be good way here

Comment: Two advantages. (1) You don't have to remove any constraints, just deactivate them, and (2) I've heard that activating an array is better performing than one-by-one.